# How to configure context path for Azure App service with Tomcat linux

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-web-app-service, tomcat9

Where can I find the tomcat installed directory on the azure app service through kudu console?

I have tried configuring the context path, by adding below in Application settings:

1. Add VM argumnets to JAVA_OPTS
   `-Dserver.servlet.context-path=/myapp`
2. Add environmental variable
   `SERVER_SERVLET_CONTEXT_PATH=/myapp`
3. Adding in the application.properties file
   `server.servlet.context-path=/myapp`

Also tried with `WebServeletCustomizer`

Please provide some solution, the app is working fine locally through IntelliJ war deployment.

Tech stack: JDK 11, Tomcat 9, Springboot 2.6.x
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To test this i have created a web app which is running with runtime stack Java 11 and Java web server stack as Apache Tomcat 9.0.

I am able see the tomcat installed directory under the path `/usr/local/tomcat` and you can add the context path in the server.xml file which is present under `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml`

Refer to this documentation for more information about [configuring tomcat java apps on app service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-java?pivots=platform-linux#tomcat-3)

Comment: I tried reaching the location you mentioned, but I don't see the tomcat folder in my case, please find the screen shots attached

Comment: @user9150771 the path i have mentioned in the above you need to check in SSH console instead of Bash. when i have checked in SSH console i am able to see the TOMCAT config under the path as shown in [this image](https://i.imgur.com/YPSHQHK.png)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the path, I tried updating the context path in the context.xml file and restarted the server, but the changes are getting lost

Comment: What command are you using for war deployment, can you please share

Comment: @user9150771 - You can use `az webapp deploy` cmdlet to deploy war,jar or zip file here is the reference documentation for that cmdlet [az webapp deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deploy)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same commands, how ever unable to change the context root